# Clean mathematical notation of a for-loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, numpy, notation

I am sorry if this doesn't really belong here but I'm looking for a way to describe the mathematical background of my code. Using numpy I sum two more dimensional arrays:

```
a.shape = (10, 5, 2)
b.shape = (5, 2)
c = a + b
c.shape = (10, 5, 2)
```

Is there a pure mathematical notation for this (so WITHOUT indroducing for-loops or numpy conventions in my text)? What I'm trying to avoid is to have to write something like this:

```
c_{1, y, z} = a_{1, y, z} + b_{y, z}

c_{2, y, z} = a_{2, y, z} + b_{y, z}

...

c_{10, y, z} = a_{10, y, z} + b_{y, z}
```

Any thoughts?

Edit: I'm using LaTeX for the documentation, so indexing is no problem. I'm currently using more or less the suggestion from Tobias. I was just hoping that there may be some other solution I haven't thought of.

Comment: Just write $C_{i,y,z}=a_{i,y,z}+b_{y,z}$ with $i=1,\ldots,10$. Sorry, looks like the maths formatting does not work here. But, I think you get the idea.

Comment: Are you asking about plain text notation (as in a code file), or with some sort of markup language (latex, markdown, rst, etc)?  The usual mathematical notion for indices uses subscripts and/or superscripts.

Comment: I think your best bet would be http://maths.stackexchange.com... If you remove the programming references and just describe how you would write it long hand, then I'm sure someone in the know can describe the correct notation for you. (And that site formats maths notation unlike SO)

Comment: @Tobias you should post your comment as the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just write

[image] for [image].

You find this form often in books on numerics like [Numerical Recipes](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=0521880688/numericalrecipesA/#reader_0521880688) (e.g., page 57).

If you have larger sections of code an alternative is to use [pseudo-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode).