# Mathematical notation of Numpy's subtract function

Tags: python, numpy, math

I noticed that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410175/clean-mathematical-notation-of-a-for-loop) has been marked as on-topic on this site, hence, I'm asking this question.

I have the following bit of code.

```
norm = np.linalg.norm(true_warped_keypoints - warped_keypoints, ord=None, axis=2)
N1 = true_warped_keypoints.shape[0]
N2 = warped_keypoints.shape[0]
distance_thresh=3
if N2 != 0:
    min1 = np.min(norm, axis=1)
    count1 = np.sum(min1 <= distance_thresh)
if N1 != 0:
    min2 = np.min(norm, axis=0)
    count2 = np.sum(min2 <= distance_thresh)
if N1 + N2 > 0:
    repeatability.append((count1 + count2) / (N1 + N2))
```

I would like to mathematically represent this code grabbed from [here](https://github.com/rpautrat/SuperPoint/blob/master/superpoint/evaluations/detector_evaluation.py). 
Let's say `true_warped_keypoints` is a numpy array of shape `10x1x2` and `warped_keypoints` is of shape `1x4x2`.

Mathematically, the **subtraction of two matrices requires same dimensions**, but numpy does element wise subtraction as in the first line of the code.

My questions are the following:

1. How do I represent the subtraction in the first line mathematically?
2. Following that representation, how do I represent `min1 = np.min(norm, axis=1)` and `min2 = np.min(norm, axis=0)` mathematically?

Here's a quick example to try out the subtraction of different shaped arrays.

```
A = np.array([[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6]]])
B = np.array([[[1,1]],[[1,2]],[[1,3]],[[1,4]],[[1,5]]])
C=A-B
```

Comment: I'm confused, if your arrays have the shapes you describe, then you should be getting an error on the first line, when you do `true_warped_keypoints - warped_keypoints`. Those shapes are not broadcastable together, so the subtraction doesn't work. Are you *sure* those are your real shapes?

Comment: Einstein notation may be the most powerful way of representing operations on many dimensions.  Or indices and explicit summations where applicable.

Comment: @Blckknght there was a small error. I had flipped the dimensions of `warped_keypoints`. It's fixed now. I've included a mini code example as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the arrays as tensors:

A = A_ijk, (where 1 ≤  i ≤ 10, j=1, 1 ≤ k ≤ 2)

and the same for B and C. Then you can define each element of C as

C_ijk = A_i1k - B_1jk (for 1 ≤ i ≤ 10, 1 ≤ j ≤ 4, 1 ≤ k ≤ 2)

Note that `A_ijk = A[i-1,j-1,k-1]`.

To represent the norm we would then define the tensor of order two:
[image]
With that defined we can now define the minimum vectors `m^1, m^2` componentwise: 
[image]

Comment: I'd like to accept this answer, but it's still only a partial answer. Please see my point #2.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm sorry I forgot that part somehow, it's now added. I know the images are to large but it's the best I could do on mobile.